# how to divide units of measurement in excel

Tags: excel, list

I am building a pricing guide in excel.
When entering a product, I list the name, size and how much I paid for it.
I want to know how to make the size divisible. for example; "32oz" would have a value of 32.

I could just create five columns, one for name of the product, one for unit of measurement, one for value, and the combination of the two; B1=32, C1=oz, D1=B1&C1, then hide the cells, but this seems sloppy.

Can I create a declaration, so excel know 32oz=32 from a list?
The point of this is to make it user friendly. If I program all the values into it, then anyone using it doesn't have to remember to unhide cells, then listing everything.

This is currently what I have:
[image: Current Sheet]

[image: Current Sheet]

Comment: So convert all my "1L" and "750ml" to ounces as well? 33oz, and 25oz?

Comment: Create a new column for the unit of measure and use a validation drop-down for that column. That may be the more "user friendly" way to go.